# How to use swiftHttp to get network stream and output the result to console

Tags: ios, cocoa, http, swift

I am a newer to study swift. I use the [swifthttp](https://github.com/daltoniam/SwiftHTTP) to get network stream to show in my console, but it doesn't work. I used the method NSURLConnection.sendsynchronousrequest , and it workd normally. Now, I want to know how to get the network stream using swiftHTTP.

My project is a CommandLine Tool , code is as follows in my main.swift

```
import Foundation
var request = HTTPTask()
request.GET("http://www.douban.com/j/app/radio/channels", parameters: nil, success: {(response: HTTPResponse) in
    if response.responseObject != nil {
        let data = response.responseObject as NSData
        let str = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println("response: \(str)") //prints the HTML of the page
    }
    },failure: {(error: NSError, response: HTTPResponse?) in
        println("error: \(error)")
})
```

Thanks !

Comment: What do you mean doesn't work. What's your console output?

Comment: just output "Program ended with exit code: 0"

Comment: I see. The request.GET actually runs async, I guess you are running your code in  main thread, then before the request comes back, your main thread exited and the program finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request runs async, before the request comes back, your main thread exited and the program finished. Add

```
sleep(30)
```

following your code. Or invest sometime in iOS concurrent programming(https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).